# Issue in Combining splitted String

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I have extracted text from "web 2.0 wikipedia" article, and splitted it into "sentences". After that, I am going to create "Strings" which each string containing 5 sentences.

When extracted, the text looks like below, in `EditText`

[image]

Below is my code

```
finalText = textField.getText().toString();

String[] textArrayWithFullStop = finalText.split("\\. ");
String colelctionOfFiveSentences = "";

List<String>textCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<textArrayWithFullStop.length;i++)
{
    colelctionOfFiveSentences = colelctionOfFiveSentences +        textArrayWithFullStop[i];
    if( (i%5==0) )
    {
        textCollection.add(colelctionOfFiveSentences);
        colelctionOfFiveSentences = "";
    }
 }
```

But, when I use the `Toast` to display the text, here what is gives

```
Toast.makeText(Talk.this, textCollection.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

As you can see, this is only one sentence! But I expected it to have 5 sentences!

And the other thing is, the second sentence is starting from somewhere else. Here how I have extracted it into `Toast`

```
Toast.makeText(Talk.this, textCollection.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

This make no sense to me! How can I properly split the text into sentences and, create `Strings` containing 5 sentences each?

Comment: As you can see, not all your sentences ends with a period and space. Some of the ends with a link to some resource, e.g. .[1]

Comment: @Admit: Yes, I need to find a soluion for this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for the first sentence, 0 % 5 = 0, so it is being added to the array list immediately. You should use another counter instead of mod.

```
finalText = textField.getText().toString();

String[] textArrayWithFullStop = finalText.split("\\. ");
String colelctionOfFiveSentences = "";
int sentenceAdded = 0;

List<String>textCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<textArrayWithFullStop.length;i++)
{
    colelctionOfFiveSentences += textArrayWithFullStop[i] + ". ";
    sentenceAdded++;
    if(sentenceAdded == 5)
    {
        textCollection.add(colelctionOfFiveSentences);
        colelctionOfFiveSentences = "";
        sentenceAdded = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: the OP could also start the loop with `i=1` and add `colelctionOfFiveSentences += textArrayWithFullStop[i-1] + ". ";`. Or if the OP wants to begin with `i=0`, then the condition becomes `if (i%5 == 4)`. imho, no need to add a counter.

Answer (score 2):

add  `". "` to  `textArrayWithFullStop[i]`

```
colelctionOfFiveSentences = colelctionOfFiveSentences + textArrayWithFullStop[i]+". ";
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you modify the mod line to this:

```
if(i%5==4)
```

you will have what you need.

You probably realize this, but there are other reasons why someone might use a ". ", that doesn't actually end a sentence, for instance

```
I spoke to John and he said... "I went to the store. 
Then I went to the Tennis courts.", 
and I don't believe he was telling the truth because 
1. Why would someone go to play tennis after going to the store and 
2. John has no legs!  
I had to ask, am I going to let him get away with these lies?
```

That's two sentences that don't end with a period and would mislead your code into thinking it's 5 sentences broken up at entirely the wrong places, so this approach is really fraught with problems. However, as an exercise in splitting strings, I guess it's as good as any other.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a side problem(splitting sentences) solution I would suggest to start with this regexp

```
string.split(".(\\[[0-9\\[\\]]+\\])? ")
```

And for main problem may be you could use [copyOfRange()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it. +1 from me. :)